# Was it necessary to delete these comments?

Tags: discussion, comment, specific-question, etiquette, deletion

First time on Meta. I made (at least) two comments on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352629/how-to-prove-that-731-829/1352660?noredirect=1#comment2751227_1352660), both of which were deleted.

I can't remember which comment was made first.

Some context to 'first comment': initially this question was closed. I voted to reopen and in the end this question was reopened. I might claim that the subsequent interest in the question justifies this. I commented along the lines of 'I am glad this question was reopened'. This has been deleted.

The second comment said roughly 'I wonder how long until someone suggests that a calculator be used'. This also been deleted... shortly afterwards a user suggested more-or-less 'use a calculator'.

Assuming these are moderator-deletions, I am asking why are they being so anal? Mathematics is a human pursuit and emotion and humour (?) are a part of the human condition.

Of the two comments, I think the 'first' was more appropriate for deletion... but the second?

Comment: A mod should (and probably will) provide a canonical answer, but here's my take. "[E]motion and humor are part of the human condition." No argument there, but SE is, by design, a question/answer site, not a discussion site. A consequence is that comments are considered ephemeral: unless a comment speaks to the *content* of a question or answer, it's considered fair game for deletion, so as not to clutter up things. You just have to get used to comments evaporating.

Comment: Likely what happened is that some user flagged as "too chatty" or something like this and a moderator agreed. The question you should try to answer is: Do you believe the comments will be useful to somebody down the road? If not, what is lost. // That being said, there are masses of comments on the site just like those, and no-one minds. But also masses of such comments get deleted. It is  not a big deal, I think.

Comment: Was it *necessary* to make these comments on the first place?

Comment: @RickDecker ""[E]motion and humor are part of the human condition." No argument there, but SE is, by design, a question/answer site, not a discussion site." I don't understand what you mean here. I wasn't trying to have a discussion. 

We have a "*add a comment |  show X more comments*" to deal with clutter in the first instance.

I have never noticed a comment evaporating and am somewhat butthurt!

Comment: @quid Too chatty? Yes perhaps to the first, not to the second comment. Are we supposed to behave like robots around here?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi is it *necessary* for to do anything on this site?

Comment: You're the one asking if it was necessary to delete the comments, @JpMcCarthy...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi good point!

Comment: There are [several similar older discussions on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comment+deletion). Usually the explanation was that the comment was flagged and then deleted by a mod. But it is worth mentioning that comment can also be deleted without moderators intervention if [enough users flag the comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11534/comments-being-deleted-mysteriously/11538#11538).

Comment: Since you also asked about humor and jokes, I will mention that there were also some discussions about "funny comments". I was able to find relatively quickly these two: [Is it okay to leave stupid comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19827/is-it-okay-to-leave-stupid-comments) and [Upvoting comments as equivalent of Facebook “like”: bad form?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16889/upvoting-comments-as-equivalent-of-facebook-like-bad-form) They seem to be somewhat related. Maybe somebody is able to find more posts from the past discussing this issue.

Comment: Comment deletions happen all the time and are quite insignificant. I do appreciate that it can be awkward when ones comments are suddenly gone but you really should not make too much of it. If I make a joke and no-one laughs it can be a bit awkward too, but usually the thing to do is basically nothing. Starting a debate and question others why they did not laugh and how this is not cool, usually would be an odd thing to do and make matter worse.

Answer (score 9):

### Totally!

We had an emergency yesterday, a dozen of our [hamsters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96356) became sick, and we had to remove some non-essential content to lessen the strain on the remaining [hamsters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114661).

---

On a less serious note: Moderators delete comments, that's part of the "job". Most comment deletions are triggered by flags, but not all. If we see comments that are obsolete, off-topic, non-constructive or too chatty, and we are in clean-up mood (otherwise we may not notice their too-chattiness [off-topicness, ...]), it can happen that they are removed without being flagged. And we are subjective, so too chatty/off-topic comments that we find *funny* have a much greater chance to not be deleted than ones we find boring.

It seems your comments were deleted as part of a clean-up of that comment thread, where comments not directly pertinent to the question - its content or its presentation - were culled. (I just continued that by deleting two comments that became obsolete by an edit. ;)

Comment: I bet [one of the snakes](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2327/7206) is responsible for the hamsters problem. I told Shog9 to use short-toed eagles!

Comment: "*On a less serious note*"?  Or do you mean "on a more serious note"?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Sick hamsters are _very_ serious. (Well, they would be if they were real, but it's the image that counts.)

Comment: @DanielFischer, I apologize for my callousness.  I hope the hamsters get well soon.